# Changing Fiddler root certificate to successfully decrypt HTTPS

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, fiddler

Is there a way to change the Fiddler's root certificate. I want it for a scenario when the client app uses certificate pinning and I have access to the keystore, whose certificate is being trusted by the client app.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're asking *"Can I change the certificate Fiddler uses for a particular site"* rather than the *root* certificate, which is used for all sites.

Yes, if you really do have the private key for the certificate, you can configure Fiddler to use it. Inside Fiddler's Rules > Customize Rules > OnBoot function, you can call either:

```
CertMaker.StoreCert("example.com", certMyCert);
```

or

```
CertMaker.StoreCert("example.com", "C:\\temp\\cert.pfx", "TopSecretPassword");
```

The first call requires that your X509Certificate2 variable (`certMyCert` in this case) refer to a certificate that is already installed in your computer's Certificate Manager (`certmgr.msc`), so its private key can be found, while the second allows you to specify a PFX file from disk.

Comment: adding self signed certificate gives HSTS error on https website, any workaround that?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; generally, new questions should be asked as new questions, not as comments on 3-year-old answers.

Comment: Worked perfect. Thanks for this.