# Intercepting HTTPS trafic with libcurl and Fiddler

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, openssl, fiddler

I have a tools that uses libcurl to issue http requests, I want to be able to view the traffic in fiddler.

We are using the OpenSSL as the TLS layer and define the approved CAs using the technique mentioned [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html).

The exact scenario is I have a web server let's call it `api.bla.example.com`.

When I configure Curl to use the host machine as a proxy, but not to decrypt the traffic, fiddler shows the tunnel and the request completes successfully.

I created a certificate (for `*.example.com`) that is signed by a non official CA. Added the cert of that CA to the list of the approved CAs and configured Fiddler to supply that certificate when accessing `api.bla.example.com` by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635673/1941161) suggestion and adding

```
CertMaker.StoreCert("api.bla.example.com", "D:\\custom.pfx", "SECRET");
```

To `OnBoot`.

However I always get the same error:

> SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

The code:

```
const std::array<const char*, 3> CERTS = {
       {
           "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"           
           "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n" , /*Official CA*/
           "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"           
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXX\n"
           "-----END CERTIFICATE-----", /* Test CA*/
           "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
           "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\n"
           "XXXXXXXX\n"
           "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" /* Itermediate Test CA*/
        } };

CURLcode approve(CURL*, void* sslctx, void*, const char * const mypem)
{
    CURLcode rv = CURLE_ABORTED_BY_CALLBACK;
    X509_STORE *store = nullptr;
    X509 *cert = nullptr;

    /* clear the current thread's OpenSSL error queue */
    ERR_clear_error();

    /* get a BIO */
    auto bio = std::unique_ptr<BIO, decltype(&BIO_free)>{ BIO_new_mem_buf(mypem, -1), &BIO_free };
    if (!bio)
    {
        return rv;
    }

    /* use it to read the PEM formatted certificate from memory into an X509
     * structure that SSL can use
     */
    if (PEM_read_bio_X509(bio.get(), &cert, 0, nullptr))
    {
        auto certPtr = std::unique_ptr<X509, decltype(&X509_free)>{ cert, &X509_free };

        /* get a pointer to the X509 certificate store (which may be empty!) */
        store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(reinterpret_cast<SSL_CTX*>(sslctx));
        if (!store)
        {
            return rv;
        }

        /* add our certificate to this store */
        if (!X509_STORE_add_cert(store, cert))
        {
            unsigned long error = ERR_peek_last_error();

            /* Ignore error X509_R_CERT_ALREADY_IN_HASH_TABLE which means the
             * certificate is already in the store. That could happen if
             * libcurl already loaded the certificate from a ca cert bundle
             * set at libcurl build-time or runtime.
             */
            if (ERR_GET_LIB(error) != ERR_LIB_X509 ||
                ERR_GET_REASON(error) != X509_R_CERT_ALREADY_IN_HASH_TABLE)
            {
                return rv;
            }

            ERR_clear_error();
        }
    }

    ERR_clear_error();

    return CURLE_OK;
}

CURLcode certificate_callback(CURL* curl, void* sslctx, void* parm)
{
    CURLcode result{ CURLE_OK };

    for (const auto& ca : CERTS)
    {
        result = approve(curl, sslctx, parm, ca);
        if (CURLE_OK != result)
        {
            return result;
        }
    }

    return result;
}



TEST(Url, MiniTest)
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    CURLcode res;
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.bla.example.com/SomeThing");

    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "FQDN.of.the.machine:9999");

    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, NULL);
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAPATH, NULL);
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, *certificate_callback);

    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

}
```

I tried (as in this example adding the intermediate CA to the approved list or just having the custom CA on it both didn't work). Unfortunately it's not clear to me what exactly doesn't match and what certificate curl could not *get*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable custom CAs one has to use the old MakeCert engine in:

> Tools -> Options -> HTTPS -> Certificates generated by CertEnroll engine

So it shows as

> Tools -> Options -> HTTPS -> Certificates generated by MakeCert engine

[image: Fiddler 4 Http Options menu]

Which will then enable you to intercept traffic while not trusting Fiddler's cert and not disabling certificate validation.